# Using StackScreen options from @react-navigation/native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I need to set a button on screen right side header.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const App = () => {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Next" component={NextScreen} options={{
          headerRight: () => <Button title="Done" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}/>,
          headerLeft:null
        }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SelectPatient" component={SelectPatientScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

error message shows that Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside ascreen in a navigator?

I also use navigation in HomeScreen and it works. Error occurs in App.js.
how can i put navigation object onPress.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an addition to [Guruparan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435722/guruparan-giritharan) answer, you can't do `const navigation = useNavigation()` outside of a navigator

Comment: Hi thanks. I put navigation to options's value, but I got another error. navigation.navigate is not a function. according to console.log, navigation is a object (and has a navigate as a function) but navigation.navigate is undefined.